# Canvas Fireworks

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to customise this script so it initiates after the mouse has been clicked.

You can view the code here, it's a long one so it will be easier for you to see it here http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/canvas-fireworks-tutorial

I have tried to wrap the code in a function eg

```
function start_fireworks() {CODE}
 $(window).click(function() {
    start_fireworks();
});
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) please. How about a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem. For all we know, you might have just forgotten to include jQuery on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's invoked this way in the example: `window.onload = loop;`.

You can change that to `$(window).click(loop);` and it should work. As @MattBall said, you need to make sure you included jQuery on the page.